# How Can I delete a Magmi Profile?

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I created a few test profiles and I need to remove them because, if selected, they could cause a lot of problems with my system.  There isn't a built in feature to remove the profiles with Magmi and I cannot find any records of the profiles in the database.  How can I remove Magmi profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  To delete a Magmi profile, log into ftp and navigate to `magmi/conf`.  The profiles are separated into sub directories.  You'll just need to delete the sub-directories of the profiles that need to be removed.

Note: Always a good idea to backup prior to doing this!

You may need to change your ownership / permissions in order to have access to delete these directories.  I actually backed up the entire `conf` directory, changed the `conf` permissions to 777 (files and sub-directories too), then deleted the entire `conf` directory and uploaded a new one without the profiles.